# How Apollo Query component use it's self value as callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I was reading apollo [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html) then I saw the below code.
it seems like loading, error, and data from Query component itself can be passed and props.children accept function. How can I implement a simple component like this that can get its own value and pass it to its child?

```js
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { Query } from "react-apollo";

const GET_DOGS = gql`
  {
    dogs {
      id
      breed
    }
  }
`;

const Dogs = ({ onDogSelected }) => (
  <Query query={GET_DOGS}>
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return "Loading...";
      if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

      return (
        <select name="dog" onChange={onDogSelected}>
          {data.dogs.map(dog => (
            <option key={dog.id} value={dog.breed}>
              {dog.breed}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      );
    }}
  </Query>
);
```

what have I tried:
1) overriding `props.children` with the function to send data with it. ( i guess apollo query component used this method since according to it's [source code](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/blob/master/src/Query.tsx). 
2) cloning children and then send data which was unsuccessful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowing the children to be a function is a common pattern in React. Even the new [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consumer) uses this pattern.

If you look at the [source code of the react-apollo Query component](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/blob/4ac3140ec4486355cb3bec1542160aded7cd4dd3/src/Query.tsx#L251) you can see it just calls the `this.props.children` as a function.

```
render() {
  const { children } = this.props;
  const queryResult = this.getQueryResult();
  return children(queryResult);
}
```

For a more in-depth explaination of the Function as children pattern, please check out the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) regarding render props.

Comment: Thanks it worked. for other users that wondering visit https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-q7zrek for demo